# Best way to dump and evaluate S3 bucket policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

i would like a simple, and as painless as possible way, to pull a bucket policy one at a time (in an account with a lot of buckets). i am mainly concerned with the IAM roles and users and what resources they have access to in the bucket. running `aws s3api get-bucket-policy` spits out more than i need in a hard to read format. i was hoping to get some sort of formatted file put together with a simple (and probably long) break down of who has access to what. any suggestions before i write a script and do this the hard way?

Comment: remember the bucket policy is one of the ways to control access to a bucket. There could be IAM policies directly assigned to the users/groups/roles that could grant access to the users as well

Comment: right. that is next.

Comment: What you want to do is a very complex tasks, which even AWS hasn't fully figured out, as evident by their policy simulator which is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

From [Using Access Analyzer for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/access-analyzer.html):

> **Access Analyzer for S3** alerts you to S3 buckets that are configured to allow access to anyone on the internet or other AWS accounts, including AWS accounts outside of your organization. For each public or shared bucket, you receive findings into the source and level of public or shared access. For example, Access Analyzer for S3 might show that a bucket has read or write access provided through a bucket access control list (ACL), a bucket policy, or an access point policy. Armed with this knowledge, you can take immediate and precise corrective action to restore your bucket access to what you intended.

This is similar to [AWS IAM Access Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/what-is-access-analyzer.html):

> **AWS IAM Access Analyzer** helps you identify the resources in your organization and accounts, such as Amazon S3 buckets or IAM roles, that are shared with an external entity. This lets you identify unintended access to your resources and data, which is a security risk. Access Analyzer identifies resources that are shared with external principals by using logic-based reasoning to analyze the resource-based policies in your AWS environment. For each instance of a resource that is shared outside of your account, Access Analyzer generates a finding. Findings include information about the access and the external principal that it is granted to. You can review findings to determine whether the access is intended and safe, or the access is unintended and a security risk.

Comment: sorry, i probably should have mentioned this in the original post. will edit. the sole purpose for this is not for the infrastructure team to utilize already known AWS tools. it is for regulatory compliance and the policy that was created. every quarter all access to buckets must be reviewed for things like access from terminated employees or that some user/system/service doesn't have a large amount of access that doesn't make sense.